# Hi, I'm trying to install mongodb on linux but got an error

Tags: mongodb

I'm installing `mognodb` following step by step of the documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/ but getting an error at the step `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org`. Can't find any info to fix this problem.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Alos I've tried to install the dependencies one by one, but still getting the same error that points on other dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Import the public key used by the package management system

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
```

Create a list file for MongoDB.

In Ubuntu 12.04 (deprecated):

```
echo "deb http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu precise/mongodb-org/3.0 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.0.list
```

In Ubuntu 14.04:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
```

In Ubuntu 16.04:

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
```

Reload local package database.

```
sudo apt-get update
```

It will throw a warning

```
W: http://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu/dists/trusty/mongodb-org/3.0/Release.gpg: Signature by key 492EAFE8CD016A07919F1D2B9ECBEC467F0CEB10 uses weak digest algorithm (SHA1)
```

Just Ignore It.

Install the MongoDB packages.

```
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

After installation you can start MongoDB using

```
sudo service mongod start
```

Comment: but what's the difference? I did literally the same several times

Comment: following the sequence of these commands is important.